# How to set up specific routing in mvc3 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have problem with routing. I have many pages on my site generated dynamically from database.

First thing which I want to accomplish is to route to these pages like that:

"How to repair a car"

www.EXAMPLE.com/How-to-repair-a-car

For now it works like that: www.EXAMPLE.com/Home/Index/How-to-repair-a-car

Secondly my default page have to be like that: www.EXAMPLE.com

On the Start Page will be news with pagging, so if someone click for instance in the "page 2" button, the address should looks: www.EXAMPLE.com/page =2

CONCLUSION:

1. default page -> www.EXAMPLE.com  (with page = 0)
2. default page with specific page of news -> www.EXAMPLE.com/page=12
3. article page -> www.EXAMPLE.com/How-to-repair-car  (without parameter 'page') routing sholud point to article or error404

PS: sorry for my english

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is? Please post your routing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create route for articles in routing config, like this:

Routing config:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(null, "{article}",
                            new {controller = "Home", action = "Article" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            var definedPage = page ?? 0;
            ViewBag.page = "your page is " + definedPage;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Article(string article)
        {
            ViewBag.article = article;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**/?page=10 - works**

**/How-to-repair-car - works**

That approach excellent works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what i wanted to achieve. I have one more little question. What have I change to change /?page=10 to:
www.EXAMPLE.com/p?page=1

Comment: What does mean 'p' (www.EXAMPLE.com/ **p** ?page=1) in that case, is it action?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, all I wanted is in your answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic routing example for www.example.com/How-to-repair-car

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Tipser.Web
{
    public class MyMvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "ArticleRoute",
                "{articleName}",
                new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index", articleName = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new { userFriendlyURL = new ArticleConstraint() }
                );
        }

        public class ArticleConstraint : IRouteConstraint
        {
            public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
            {
                var articleName = values["articleName"] as string;
                //determine if there is a valid article
                if (there_is_there_any_article_matching(articleName))
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```